# Error msg with NetCDF: "open_dataset() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘mode’"

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to run a Bayesian regression. The posterior distribution is saved with an extension .nc as NetCDF.

When creating the samples, I need to open up this file by:

```
 data_posterior = az.from_netcdf(‘./…/posterior_9_deciles_healthy_Male_i1.nc’)
```

This gives me an error saying `open_dataset() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘mode’`
I suspect it has to do with something deeper in the command, when it passes through xr.open_dataset(filename, mode=”r”), because this is also referenced in the error msg.

Any ideas on how this could be helped?

Thanks